# How to move the buttons in a React Swiper

Tags: reactjs, react-swiper

I'm using the React Swiper component (https://swiperjs.com/react#swiper-props) and I need a way to move the two buttons to change slide because they get over my other components.

I want them to be on the side of the black box.

As suggested by @Guillaume I have to change the "swiper-button-prev" and "swiper-button-next" css classses

[image]

Comment: If you want the complete customization you can override the button classes : `swiper-button-prev` and `swiper-button-next`